# How does one efficiently override the draw method of a sprite to change individual pixels?

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

Apparently in cocos2d-x, you can override the draw method of a sprite, to do interesting things. Unfortunately, I have no OpenGL experience, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going on in this method:

```
void Sprite::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
#if CC_USE_CULLING
    // Don't do calculate the culling if the transform was not updated
    auto visitingCamera = Camera::getVisitingCamera();
    auto defaultCamera = Camera::getDefaultCamera();
    if (visitingCamera == defaultCamera) {
        _insideBounds = ((flags & FLAGS_TRANSFORM_DIRTY)|| visitingCamera->isViewProjectionUpdated()) ? renderer->checkVisibility(transform, _contentSize) : _insideBounds;
    }
    else
    {
        _insideBounds = renderer->checkVisibility(transform, _contentSize);
    }

    if(_insideBounds)
#endif
    {
        _trianglesCommand.init(_globalZOrder, _texture->getName(), getGLProgramState(), _blendFunc, _polyInfo.triangles, transform, flags);
        renderer->addCommand(&_trianglesCommand);

#if CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW
        _debugDrawNode->clear();
        auto count = _polyInfo.triangles.indexCount/3;
        auto indices = _polyInfo.triangles.indices;
        auto verts = _polyInfo.triangles.verts;
        for(ssize_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //draw 3 lines
            Vec3 from =verts[indices[i*3]].vertices;
            Vec3 to = verts[indices[i*3+1]].vertices;
            _debugDrawNode->drawLine(Vec2(from.x, from.y), Vec2(to.x,to.y), Color4F::WHITE);

            from =verts[indices[i*3+1]].vertices;
            to = verts[indices[i*3+2]].vertices;
            _debugDrawNode->drawLine(Vec2(from.x, from.y), Vec2(to.x,to.y), Color4F::WHITE);

            from =verts[indices[i*3+2]].vertices;
            to = verts[indices[i*3]].vertices;
            _debugDrawNode->drawLine(Vec2(from.x, from.y), Vec2(to.x,to.y), Color4F::WHITE);
        }
#endif //CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW
    }
}
```

Given pixels, I know how to transform my image (individual pixels) to get my desired result, but this involves iterating through all the pixels in the image and making changes as necessary, furthermore, I can do this before run time (offline, before building my app) to create static images, which I use in the app. I am trying to figure out how I can do the same thing at runtime (efficiently), since I'm guessing the same technique I use for generating images uses a lot of CPU (since I'm iterating over pixels and not using OpenGL).

Can someone point me in the right direction ? I'm not trying to build a graphics engine or anything... I'm just trying to modify pixels quickly at runtime....

Comment: I may be wrong with my limited Cocos2D knowledge, but in the given method you are commiting your draw call to OpenGL/Cocos with `renderer->addCommand(&_trianglesCommand)`. You are not modifying single pixels here, but commit the polygon as such for a draw call to the GPU. In case you have debug draw (`CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW`) you are still only drawing the outlines of the polygons with white lines and not single pixels. The pixels are generated when rendering on the GPU side.

So, probably I didn't understand the question yet: What do you mean by not modifying the single pixels on the CPU?

Comment: If I just have an array or pointer of unsigned char*, then I can modify the pixels by changing each of the component values in the array. This is CPU intensive, since I have to modify the data and then recreate the image / sprite / animation.. It doesn't use the GPU at all. I don't know anything about OpenGL. What do you mean by commit the polygon ? What can you actually do by overriding the draw method ?